# Weight sum and square form

Tags: android, view, android-layout-weight

I have `LinearLayout` which contains two `Button` widgets with `layout_weight=1`. Depends on length of `Button`'s text or screen resolution I get buttons with rectangular form *(gray rectangles)* but I need to keep the square form *(blue squares)*.
[image]

I was trying to change `height` of `LinearLayout` param in `onStart()` method, depends on `Button`'s `width`, but `getWidth()` returns `0`. I understand that it's because view at that moment still not rendered. Please, help me to solve my problem.

Comment: is my solution worked out...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a custom view to set the view's height to be tha same as its width by overriding onMeasure:

```
public class SquareButton extends Button {

    public SquareButton (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }
}
```

All you have to is use the custom button in your xml layout and you don't have to do anything in the activity:

```
<com.package.name.SquareButton
    android:layout_with="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. If you need to find the real width of an element, you can:

1)  attach an [`OnGlobalLayoutListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) to the view's [`ViewTreeObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) (but remember to remove it when you are done)

2) or you can **manually measure** what you need:

```
 if(view.getMeasuredHeight() == 0){
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    view.measure( metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels );
 }
 int realHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
 //...your code
```

Comment: same and nice. answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly right because at that time view will not be drawn so for that you have to use viewtreeobserver:

like this:

```
        final ViewTreeObserver treeObserver = viewToMesure
                .getViewTreeObserver();

        treeObserver
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println(viewToMesure.getHeight()
                                + "SDAFASFASDFas");
                        heith = viewToMesure.getHeight();


                    }
                });
```

this view tree observer will be called after creating the view based on that you calculate and you can change.

Comment: And if I have several LinearLayout I need to create new treeObserver for each LinearLayout ?

Comment: you didn't mention any listiview in question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean LinearLayout... )))

Comment: for each button you have to create one.

Comment: So my steps: 1) Create observer for any button 2) Get width of any button. 3) Delete that Observer 4) Get Observers of my LinearLayouts 4)Change their height. That's all?

Comment: there is no need to use a ViewTreeObserver if you make a custom view

Comment: @Longi if you want to set that particular height to another view at that time how u will get that height from custom view to activity.

Comment: why would you want to set the height to another view, when all he wants are square shaped buttons? Using a ViewTreeObserver is more expensive as onGlobalLayout is called everytime the layout is changed

Comment: @Longi in question he mentioned he will get the button length and he want to set to some thing else so.

Comment: No, he wants square shaped buttons and he tried getting it by setting the height of the LinearLayout programatically. And my solution of getting square shaped buttons doesn't require setting the height of the LinearLayout.

Comment: at that time question should be how to create squared buttons.